# Cannot change LC_CTYPE env variable, why?

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8

On my new Ubuntu 13.10, I try to change LC_CTYPE to zh_CN.UTF-8 in terminal, but it does not work. My locale output always is below:

```
dean@dean-ubuntu:~$ export LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
dean@dean-ubuntu:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Any idea?

Comment: It works for me. And if I set `$LC_CTYPE` to a locale that doesn't exist (`"ma_MA.utf9"`, Martian UTF-9), I get some error messages, but the bad locale name still shows up in the output of the `locale` command. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 (more or less).

Comment: It worked on my old computers before, still Ubuntu 13.10. But I cannot do the same thing on my new computer. How to find the real reason?

Comment: It does work, but bash gives you a warning, also programs cannot use the selected locale. Check `localedef --list-archive` for the usable values; check `man locale-gen` for creating more choices.

Comment: On Ubuntu, add the new entry to file `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and run `locale-gen`